# Allow write access to a folder for only specific web users

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7, forms-authentication

I have a website that is written in C# that uses Forms Authentication to allow users to access additional content on the site.  Some of those users have an aspnet role I created called Admin. These users only can add content to the site including uploading images.

What is the proper way to give these specific users write access to the images folder and only give other users read access?

I looked at using pass-through authentication on my IIS7 server but I can't add all of the users to folder permissions because new users are being added all the time.  I also thought about using a virtual directory but I wasn't sure how to make that work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is best practice, but you can setup impersonation in your web.config file for a specific directory:

```
<location path="UploadPath">
  <system.web>
   <identity impersonate="true" userName="impersonatedUser" password="******"/>
   <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow roles="Admin"/>
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>
```

Some more information on impersonation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should have a virtual directory where all the files uploaded will go, preferably separated by User1, User2 folders. That virtual directory will be configured under a user that has permissions to write to the folders underneath. I don't think there is anyway you can control the read/write access to that using forms authentication. You will have to restrict the access to the upload page/functionality on the web application using forms authentication roles.

Comment: How would I use the forms authentication roles?  Like what is the code?

Comment: You will say If(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin")) { pnlUpload.Enabled = true; } , for example.